# ssh into server behind a gatekeeper in one step (involving sudo)

Tags: ssh, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [non-interactive ssh sudo… prompts for the password in plain text](https://superuser.com/questions/256981/non-interactive-ssh-sudo-prompts-for-the-password-in-plain-text)

Here's the current workflow I have (already have some settings in my `.ssh/config`):

```
scribu@localhost$ ssh core
scribu@core$ sudo ssh app-01
[sudo] password for scribu:
root@app-01$
```

Is there any way I could shorten that to a single command, similar to this?

```
scribu@localhost$ ssh app-01
[sudo] password for scribu:
root@app-01$
```

I tried the ProxyCommand method, suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/107679/forward-ssh-traffic-through-a-middle-machine):

```
Host app-01
    ProxyCommand ssh core "sudo /bin/nc -w1 %h"
```

but it doesn't work because it won't let me input the password for sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's quite simple:

```
ssh core -t "sudo ssh app-01"
```

More info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48530/4584

And if you want to give a more descriptive text for the sudo prompt, you can do:

```
ssh core -t "sudo -p '[sudo] password for %u@%h: ' ssh db-slave-01"
```